# Builder pattern or pipeline in data processing in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a script using pandas that preprocesses two datafiles and returns one file.
Basically the structer looks like

```
read file1 to dataframe
read file2 to dataframe
process file1
process file2
merge files
process the result file
... more functions that process the dataframe
return file
```

And I want to itegrate this process into my web application.
I assume that I should create some class such as "InputFilesProcessor" and in my application create such an object that will process the file:

```
p = InputFilesProcessor()
result = p.process(file1, file2)
```

I am not sure if the process method should use some pipeline or should I use builder pattern and use some Builder object? and run all the functions on it?
Is there any common practice? I think that process function would look quite odd if I will run 20 funtions on it:

```
  df = fun1(df)
  df = fun2(df)
  df = fun3(df)
  ... and so on..
```

Comment: Thats probably a question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @bgse no, it isn't, unless all code is included and works. Please see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users.